# Mounting SSHFS for local folder on Mac OS X to edit files on Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: macos, ubuntu, ssh, fuse, sshfs

I want to be able to edit files locally using a nice IDE and have the files 
on my local machine (`~/Code/myproject`) get immediately pushed to the Ubuntu machine in the cloud (`/home/ubuntu/myproject`).

I installed [FUSE and SSHFS](https://osxfuse.github.io/) for my Mac OS X laptop (local) machine.

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 AWS instance on EC2:

```
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxx:~$ uname -a
Linux ip-xxxxxx 4.4.0-1017-aws #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 19:48:19 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ip-xxxxxxx:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

I use a `.pem` file to SSH into that box with the `-i` flag (haven't set up authorized_keys).

So here's what I do on local machine:

```
$ mount  # check for mounted
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)

$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/aws.pem,loglevel=debug \
    ubuntu@ec2-xxxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/myproject \
    /Users/me/Code/myproject
```

It prompts me for local machine password and then I see the following:

```
Password:
remote host has disconnected
```

Clearly, something has mounted though:

```
$ mount
/dev/disk1 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
ubuntu@ec2-xxxxxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/myproject on /Users/me/Code/myproject (osxfuse, synchronous)
```

and if I try the same `sshfs` command as above again (without `unmoun`-ting) I get a different error:

```
mount_osxfuse: mount point /Users/me/Code/myproject is itself on a OSXFUSE volume
```

I can unmount and try again with `sudo diskutil umount force /Users/me/Code/myproject/` but I get the same original error when I try again.

I thought perhaps it was a problem with my remote server's SFTP so I located all the `sftp-server` location on the remote box:

```
$ sudo find / | grep sftp-server
...
/usr/lib/sftp-server
/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
```

And then I tried with both in my `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file with the line:

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/sftp-server
```

but neither configuration after a reboot seems to work.

I can SFTP in with the following command:

```
$ sftp -i ~/.ssh/aws.pem ubuntu@ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Connected to ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com.
sftp>
```

EDIT: running the `debug3` loglevel gives relatively the same results:

```
$ sudo sshfs -o allow_other,defer_permissions,IdentityFile=~/.ssh/aws.pem,loglevel=debug3 ubuntu@ec2-xxxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/ubuntu/myproject /Users/me/Code/myproject
sudo: cannot get working directory
The authenticity of host 'ec2-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
remote host has disconnected
```

Any ideas on what to fix / where the issue could be?

Comment: Can you connect with `sftp` on that server?

Comment: Yes I can. So the sftp server is running

Comment: Give it a try with `loglevel=debug3` and post the output.

Comment: @Jakuje updated. I get the same output though. Still the error message with `remote host has disconnected`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are running the `sshfs` under `sudo`, which makes the difference from running the `sftp` as your user, becuause the `root` can not find your authentication keys:

```
IdentityFile=~/.ssh/aws.pem
```

expands to your home directory for your user (`/home/your-user/.ssh/aws.pem`), but to `root` home for `sudo` user (`/root/.ssh/aws.pem`), where the file obviously is not.

Use the full path to the PEM file, such as

```
IdentityFile=/home/your-user/.ssh/aws.pem`
```

Comment: Btw, is `sudo diskutil umount force /Users/me/Code/myproject` the best way to unmount?

Comment: According to https://github.com/libfuse/sshfs/ `umount mountpoint` should do the job (of course with `sudo` if you mounted with `sudo`).